# What is the best way to map following unstructured data in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, foselasticabundle

I am trying to figure out what could be the best type and anlyzer for a field which has unstructured data.

request field could be of following and many other

1. {"_format":"json","follow":{"followee":27}} //nested objects
2. [{"q": "madhab"}] //array of objects
3. ?q=madhab  //string

i have tried making this field text with simple analyzer

```
"request": {
    "type": "text",
    "analyzer": "simple"
},
```

Plus: i wonder if there is any online tool which can help to visualize how  elastic search tokenize the data with given analyzers, filters

Comment: and it didn't work? or didn't match your expectations? what's the problem here?

Comment: It didn't match my expectation in fact. I want to  search using keyword where my keyword can be any words in that data, of the above format. I am not sure whether simple analyzer will be efficient for the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elastic search gives you an option to see how the text has been tokenized under various analyzers. You can use Kibana or any REST client to see the response for such request:

GET /_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "standard",
  "text": "Text to analyze"
}

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/analysis-intro.html

This will give you fair idea what is missing in your schema w.r.t your queries.